# Restful webservices Struts 2

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, struts2

I understand this might be a vague question but since I am new to this technology, I think better to to know all aspects before I start.

I want to build a restful webservice around an existing Strut 2 web application which is working and it should work as an independent web app also. Objective is to provide api to the android app.

I have started a demo with jersey and built few urls but with hard-coded data. For now, I am using basic authentication. I have to oauth also. I have googled and found that there is [REST](http://struts.apache.org/docs/rest-plugin.html) plugin and then Convention plugin. What are the pros and cons if I am using jersey and not REST plugin? I guess Convention plugin is optional but still what I am losing by not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST plugin offers you a custom request dispatcher that interprets the request URI for you and invokes very specific methods to handle the combination of HTTP method and URI attribute values.

For example:

[image]

The benefit to using the REST plugin is that you simply need to create an action that adheres to the REST plugin's method invocation conventions and the rest happens seamlessly.

That said, if you're not bound to using REST based URIs, you can very easily accomplish similar APIs using the JSON plugin to output JSON responses and leverage Struts2's normal parameter injection functionality provided by standard HTTP requests.

As for the convention plugin, it merely offers you a way to have Struts automatically wire up your actions for you without using XML.  It's entirely optional and not necessary unless you want to do so.

Comment: Thanks Naros for explaining.